# How to configure Rebus manualy to use external server

Tags: rebus

I've got a app.config configuration for Rebus and it works:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="rebus" type="Rebus.Configuration.RebusConfigurationSection, Rebus" />
  </configSections>
  <rebus address="192.168.10.100" inputQueue="a.messages" errorQueue="a.error" workers="1" maxRetries="10">
    <endpoints>
      <add messages="ESB_Model" endpoint="a.messages@MyRemoteMachine" />
    </endpoints>
  </rebus>
</configuration>
```

After now I want to set the address and endpoint in code instead of configfile:

```
_adapter = new BuiltinContainerAdapter();

        _bus = Configure.With(_adapter)
            .Logging(l => l.None())
            .Transport(t => t.UseMsmq("a.messages@MyRemoteMachine", "a.error"))
            .MessageOwnership(d => d.FromRebusConfigurationSection())
            .CreateBus()
            .Start();
```

This is not accepted and I'm not sure how to set the IP-address. Any help would be welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see a couple of issues with your code, first one being that the two configurations are not equivalent.

The issue with the second configuration is that Rebus does not allow you to use a remote queue as your endpoint's input queue. Therefore, the @-syntax should not be used when defining the input queue.

Also, it seems you're mixing something up - `a.messages` seems to be your input queue, but it also seems that you want to use it (granted: on another machine) as the owner of all messages from `ESB_Model`. It might be correct, but it seems you're mixing it up a little bit.

Usually, each endpoint should have its own unique input queue, and endpoints should always receive their messages from a local queue. And you should probably never have two endpoints receiving messages from the same queue.

Lastly: Unless you really know what you're doing, please don't explicitly specify the IP address of your endpoint - Rebus will automatically use the input queue in combination with the machine name as the address - e.g. if an endpoint `a.messages` running on `SomeMachine` sends a message to another endpoint, the return address will automatically be set as `a.messages@SomeMachine`.

If you'd like some more inspiration, you can check out the samples: https://github.com/mookid8000/Rebus/tree/master/samples/Rebus.Samples - the pub/sub sample has some simple configurations that work fine and don't over-specify.

Hope that clears it up a little bit - please let me know if you need more help :)

Comment: Let me explain THE situation a little better. I've got 1 broker (server) and 5 workers. The broker recieves messages and needs to dispatch them to the workers. I want the workers to subscribe at THE broker for certain types of messages.